# Map Symfony form clicked button to data class

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have a collection in Symfony form with multiple buttons and I need to determine which button was clicked. I know It can be done calling `isClicked()` method on that button element, but I'd like to map this clicked button into data class, is that possible?

My basic form:

```
    $builder->add(
        'items',
        'collection',
        [
            'type' => new ItemForm(),
            'label' => FALSE,
        ]
    );
```

`ItemForm`:

```
    $builder->add(
        'isRemoved',
        'submit'
    );
```

And data class for `ItemForm`:

```
class ItemFormData
{
    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    private $isRemoved = FALSE;

    /**
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isIsRemoved()
    {
        return $this->isRemoved;
    }

    /**
     * @param boolean $isRemoved
     */
    public function setIsRemoved($isRemoved)
    {
        $this->isRemoved = $isRemoved;
    }
}
```

And what I need is to map TRUE to `isRemoved` property if appropriate button was clicked. I'm using Symfony 2.7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, I've found the solution. It can be easily done using form events:

```
    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
        function (FormEvent $event) {
            $formData = $event->getData();
            $form = $event->getForm();

            if ($form['isRemoved']->isClicked()) {
                $formData->setIsRemoved(TRUE);
            }
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Peter.

I'm not sure that you can do like that.

IMO you can simple do something like that:

Create hidden field in form:

```
$builder->...
        ->add('isRemoved', 'hidden')
        ->...;
```

In template just simply render it:

```
{{ form_rest(form) }}
```

And set it field with JS:

```
$('#<form_selector>').on('submit', function () {
    $('#<is_removed_vields_selector>').val();
});
```

Or use on button click event.